# Solving for possible combinations of variables that add up to a certain number or range of numbers

Tags: math, combinations, mathematical-optimization

Good evening all, this is my first question and I am hoping someone on here might be able to at least point me in a direction.

I am trying to figure out how to optimally stack pallets in a new storage facility.  I need to configure the racking ahead of time in order to accept different sized pallets.

I am thinking of using between 3-6 different pallet height openings, say 105", 100", 84", 78", 72" and 66".

What I need to do is figure out every possible combination of these pallet heights that will have the top of the top beam at, say, 439".

An example of a combination would be (1) 105" pallet, (1) 100" pallet and (3) 78" pallets.

Another example would be (1) 105" pallet, (1) 100" pallet, (1) 84" pallet, (1) 78" pallet and (1) 72" pallet.

Obviously there are a number of these combinations...and I need to find them all.

I'm wondering if this is possible with excel? I just discovered "Solver" but haven't quite figured it out yet.

Any input would be greatly appreciated. I am kind of running in circles here...

Answer (score 0):

Using a bit of Python and the constraint solver https://pypi.org/project/python-constraint/:

```
import constraint

h = [105, 100, 84, 78, 72]  # heights
total = 439
n = len(h)  # number of different heights
# max number of pallets that can fit
Max = int(max([total/h[i] for i in range(n)]))  

problem = constraint.Problem()
problem.addVariables( [f"h{j}" for j in h], range(Max+1) )
problem.addConstraint(constraint.MaxSumConstraint(total,h))
s = problem.getSolutions()
print(f"number of solutions:{len(s)}")
print(s)
```

Output:

```
number of solutions:194
[{'h100': 4, 'h105': 0, 'h72': 0, 'h78': 0, 'h84': 0},
{'h100': 3, 'h105': 1, 'h72': 0, 'h78': 0, 'h84': 0},
{'h100': 3, 'h105': 0, 'h72': 1, 'h78': 0, 'h84': 0},
...
{'h100': 0, 'h105': 0, 'h78': 0, 'h84': 0, 'h72': 1},
{'h100': 0, 'h105': 0, 'h78': 0, 'h84': 0, 'h72': 0}]
```

Comment: Erwin, wow. That was fast.  I am not a coder - but I tried to learn python a while back.  I will have to dig into this and see if I can understand it. Thanks for doing this and giving me a direction to follow!

Comment: The code can be improved a bit (e.g. use individual bounds instead of an overall one), but it is good enough for a first attempt.